# MONGODB: find all occurencies of first or lastname according to one query

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, server

I want to find all occurencies on my DB according to firstname and lastname (the user is invited to enter what ever he wants in the search bar), and I'm supposed to return all persons who has firstname or lastname which matches that query.

I already have a solution, but I feel that there will be a better one.
Here's mine :

```
maladeModel.find ({},{nom: 1, prenom: 1, dateNaissance :1, adresse :1, photoIdentite :1},(err, malades) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json ({
                type: "Err" ,
                message : "Server not responding"
            });
        }
        return malades;
    }).then (malades=> 
       {
            malades = malades.filter(malade=> {
               return malade.nom.toUpperCase().includes(req.body.key.toUpperCase())
               ||
                malade.prenom.toUpperCase().includes(req.body.key.toUpperCase())
            });
           res.status(200).json ({type :"Info",  message: "Le malade est trouve" , malades});
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this one mongodb aggregate inbuild filter is always optimal to use.

```
 maladeModel.aggregate([
    {
           $project:{
               nom: { $toLower: "$nom" },
               prenom: { $toLower: "$prenom" },
               dateNaissance :1, adresse :1, photoIdentite :1
             }

    },
     {
       $match:{
             $or:[
                   {nom: req.body.key.toLowerCase()},
                   {prenom: req.body.key.toLowerCase()}
                 ]
             }
    }

    ]).exec(function(err, malades) {
    res.status(200).json ({type :"Info",  message: "Le malade est trouve" , malades});
    });
```

Comment: This works, but it requires that the query matchs exatly with the one in DB, but I need something like : I have 'Raiah' in my db, when I enter "rai" I'll get "Raiah" as a response. I've added the $in aggregation, but it doesnt work

Comment: don't worry just go for how do we can match regex in aggregate. will sort out your problem

Answer (score 0):

for simplicity you can just do

```
    maladeModel.find({
      $or:[
      {nom: req.body.key.toLowerCase()},
      {prenom: req.body.key.toLowerCase()}
     ]
     }, {dateNaissance :1, adresse :1, photoIdentite :1}).then(malades =>{
     res.status(200).json({type :"Info",  message: "Le malade est trouve" , malades});
    }).catch(err => res.status(500).json({message: err.message}))
```

this will get you all the matching documents in your database but I think [indexing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) is the fastest. You can check it

Comment: $match is used as an aggregation, so we should use it in the aggregate method, it gave me a an error.